# how to update user default value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have dictionary value saved in user default plist that save user email and login status like this

```
let userData : [String:Any] = [

"email" : StringValue
"hasBeenLoggedIn : BooleanValue

]

UserDefaults.standard.set(userData, forKey: "userData")
```

[image]

i want to update the value of `hasBeenLoggedIn` to true(Yes). how do i do that in swift ?

Comment: Literally the first link on google : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue

Comment: ReadIt.ChangeIt.WriteIt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```swift
var rr  = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "userData")
rr?["hasBeenLoggedIn"] = true
UserDefaults.standard.set(rr, forKey: "userData")
```

Comment: Don't suggest a forced cast, in particular not to a beginner.

Comment: The current answer won't work. There won't be a value for "userData" after a fresh install of the app. So `rr` will be `nil`. So nothing will be written to user defaults.