# How would you use .updateValue() to add a sub-dictionary to a UserDefaults dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, syntax, nsuserdefaults

Is this proper syntax for this line of code? If not what would be the correct syntax and why so?

`UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "mainDict")?.updateValue(subDict, forKey: "subDictTitle")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558115/how-to-update-user-default-value-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to store Userdefault dictionary to a temporary dictionary. Then you have to add data to a temporary dictionary.

No need to update the dictionary to Userdefault. When you store Dictionary to the Usedefault with the same key, it will replace the older dictionary to the new one.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(YOUR_TEMPORARY_DICTIONARY, forKey: YOUR_KEY_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`updateValue(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127179-updatevalue) is a *mutating* instance method for the dictionary, which means that it updates the value of the dictionary. Obviously, In order to mutate an instance, it has to be mutable, which is *not* the case when calling `UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "mainDict")`.

Even if you did:

```
let myDict = ["k1": "Hello"]
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["myDict": myDict])

var mutable = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "myDict")!
mutable["k1"] = "HEY"
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "myDict")) // Optional(["k1": Hello])
```

the value of the dictionary set in the user default won't change because simply `mutable` is a *copy* of it.

To clarify, it's similar to implementing:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["k2": "this is my string"])
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "k2") = "new string"
```

which generates the error of

> Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value

---

So, in order to resolve this issue, what you should do is to set a new value (updated dictionary) to the user defaults with the same key:

```
var myDict = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "myDict")
myDict?.updateValue("Hey", forKey: "k1")
UserDefaults.standard.set(myDict, forKey: "myDict")
```